# Refresh a list webpart to reflect the item added developed using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a visual webpart that list the students. Also have a webpart to add/edit student. after deploying the application, I created new webpart page and added CreateStudent webpart in a zone and ListStudent webpart in another zone. When i add a student I need to find that student details in the grid of ListStudent webpart. I think i need to connect the two webparts making CreateStudent webpart as provider webpart and ListStudent webpart as consumer webpart. 
But my doubt is, I dont need to pass any particular value to the ListStudent webpart. I have a funstion call in ListStudent webpart Page_Load which set the datasource of the gridview and binding it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding to the question here is my analysis.

CreateStudent - will add the student details to a list 
ListStudent - a grid showing the student details (all student details) from the list

When you add a student info through a web part (CreateStudent) and all the student records are shown in the ListStudent grid then there is no need for connecting the web parts.

Connecting web parts are only helpful when you pass any information from one web part to another and based on the sender info a different functionality will be executed in receiver end.

I prefer once you add the student information in Create Student web part just do a refresh of the page and it will load the ListStudent web part from the updated list source.

Hope this might help you!

Comment: your understanding of my query is perfect. but i want to know how to refresh ListStudent webpart from CreateStudent? I dont want to reload the entire page with postback